# Using Drools to find the best price ... not working

Tags: java, drools

Have a collection of Suppliers that quote prices and have a drools rule to find the best supplier (with the least price) and it does not seem to work as expected ...

Here is the Supplier POJO:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Supplier {
    private String supplier;
    private String product;
    private double price;
}
```

Here is the Drools DRL:

```
global org.slf4j.Logger log;

rule "Find_Best_Supplier"
    when
        $suppliers: Collection(size > 0)
        $best: Supplier() from $suppliers
        exists Supplier($best.price < price) from $suppliers
    then
        log.info("{}: Supplier {} is preferred for Product {}",
            drools.getRule().getName(),
            $best.getSupplier(),
            $best.getProduct());

        delete($suppliers);
        insert($best);
end
```

Here is the main code segment that inserts and fires the rules:

```
Supplier s1 = new Supplier("S1", "P1", 18.99);
Supplier s2 = new Supplier("S2", "P1", 18.59);
Supplier s3 = new Supplier("S3", "P1", 18.79);

KieSession ks = container.newKieSession();
ks.setGlobal("log", log);
ks.insert(Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3));
ks.insert(in);
ks.insert(th);
ks.insert(pm);
ks.fireAllRules();
ks.dispose();
```

In the logs, it shows - Find_Best_Supplier: Supplier S3 is preferred for Product P1 ... it should have picked S2 ...

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181752/drools-using-accumulate-to-find-min-and-max/7190650) seems to be discussing your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just for others benefit ... this is the corrected DRL:

```
rule "Find_Best_Supplier"
    when
        $suppliers: Collection(size > 0)
        $best: Supplier($low: price) from $suppliers
        not Supplier(price < $low) from $suppliers
    then
        log.info("{}: Supplier {} is preferred for Product {}",
            drools.getRule().getName(),
            $best.getSupplier(),
            $best.getProduct());

        delete($suppliers);
        insert($best);
end
```

Comment: This would be a better answer for future viewers if you explained why this works and what you were doing wrong in the original.